# I need help debouncing a push button

Tags: digital-logic, buffer, schmitt-trigger, debounce

I am trying to debounce a button.
Here is my result so far after placing a 1uF ceramic capacitor in parallel with the button:
[image]
[image]

This should work as an input to my Arduino 5V since it has High: U >= Vht = 3.0 V and Low: U <= Vlt = 1.5 V.

I guess this means my Arduino has a Schmitt trigger on its input pins?

I want to send my trigger signal to another digital input (a framegrabber that starts recording images on rising edge and stops on falling edge) and I do not know if it has a Schmitt trigger on its input.

I am therefore looking for a Schmitt trigger IC that can clean up and make my signal TTL 5V digital.

Could you recommend such an IC that is DIP (not surface mounted) and can be bought in small quantities?

I think I understand how I could debounce using the Arduino by measuring time from rising edge and making sure that a falling edge is not delivered too soon after that.

However I would prefer to do this in hardware for the learning experience.
Unless that is software debouncing is somehow better than hardware debouncing.

Comment: You can debounce in firmware.

Comment: Your input does not have a Schmitt trigger, it just has a band in which the input state is not considered stable. As mentioned by Eugene it's always a good idea to do debouncing in software.

Comment: To join in the chorus *"Debounce in software"*, the simplest method is when the push button is first detected as activated (usually it's active low), then start a timing loop and wait 2 or 3 ms.  If, after the timing loop expires, the switch is still detected as activated, count that as a **single** switch-active event. Then monitor the switch for release.  And debounce the switch release as well.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I send my trigger signal into my Arduino and implement debouncing in software here? I have considered this. However this ties up my Arduino which I want to use for other things.

Comment: well, there is re-entrant coding.  which means you have to time-stamp events.  what is your main event loop doing that it can't be bothered to be watching the buttons and controls?

Comment: [i just did a quick google and this article says](https://www.eejournal.com/article/ultimate-guide-to-switch-debounce-part-4/#:~:text=As%20Jack%20Ganssle%20reported%20in,microseconds%20(or%206.2%20ms).) that the longest bounce duration is as long as 6.2 ms.  that seems awful long.  the average bounce duration was 1.6 ms, which aligns with my memory of it.

Comment: Not a good idea to short out a 1 uF charged capacitor - use a 100 ohm in series.

Comment: i really think you should have a 10K pullup resistor connected to a 0.01 uF cap that goes to ground, and your momentary-contact switch connected across the cap.  so the voltage is normally high and pushing the button brings it to ground.  that's *"active low"* and the normal way of doing it.  sometimes they leave off the cap, which makes debouncing even more important.

Comment: @Andy aka: I have a 150 ohm resistor and a led in series with the capacitor/switch.

Comment: 150 ohms is ***way*** too small resistance.  this is **electronics** not some power switch.

Comment: @Andy the HC126 does not have schmitt trigger input. Search for schmitt trigger chips instead. I have to agree that shorting a 1uF capacitor with a pushbutton is not very good idea, it could eventually wear out from the multi-ampere jolts.

Comment: I would think the current trough the capacitor would be restricted to 33 mA. I think my explanation was not clear so I added a diagram.

Comment: @justme: I seem to only find inverting or nand schmitt trigger ics. Could I use e.g. SN74HC14N and run my signal in trough it "twice" to negate the inverting?

Comment: I always recommend debouncing in firmware instead of hardware. One very simple way is to read the io pin every 100 or 200 ms only.

Comment: @mkeith: why is debouncing in software better than in hardware?

Comment: @Andy Properly debouncing in HW can be challenging. Also, adding components to the PCB adds cost and takes up board space. If the FW is going to be designed to tolerate bounce (which it should) then it is easier to just do it all in FW.

Comment: @Andy When there is 5V over the capacitor, and you push the button, there is nothing else than button, wires, and capacitor themselves to limit the current. It is a short circuit. If you use HC14, then invert twice, or reverse the button so one inverter is needed. And if hardware debouncing is not needed it does not need to be done, but if some hardware is sensitive to bouncing then it has to be debounced. Reading an IO pin with does not need debouncing. Generating interrupts from pushbutton is another matter.

Comment: Instantaneous current of shorting out a 1 uF capacitor charged to circa 3 to 5 volts is going to be a 20 to 50 amps. That will generate EMI and, on a bad layout (and even some supposedly good layouts) might cause a reset.

Comment: @Andy aka: ok I finally think I got it. When I press the button current wil start flowing from one side of the capacitor to the other trough the button. So the solution to this is to place as you  mentioned earlier a 100 ohms directly after the capacitor?

Comment: Unambiguously in series with the push button..

Comment: @Andy that's not a good place for the resistor. If there is a scratchy switch connection, the cap does not have time to discharge much, and the scope probe would see 5V when button makes contact and 0V when contact disconnects and even a schmitt trigger will output bouncy signal.

Comment: 74xx14, CD40106, xx4584, ....  (xx = various) || See selector guide [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/logic-gates-and-inverters/705?s=N4IgTCBcDaIBYFMAeACAzgYzgWwJYBd8V8AnXAc3IRJAF0BfIA) BUT, do it in software :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old maxim 'garbage in, garbage out' rings true. Even if it was a 'perfect' switch, you'd still want to verify that the input is what you expect. Reading the state once means transients like ESD or lightning can get interpreted as a valid key press. What we really want to do is read the input multiple times over a given time period to ensure the input is what we think it is. The more times we read it, the more we can be sure. If we read the input every 10ms and count if we get 5 of the same input each time, then the likelihood of the switch actually being in a given state is much higher that if we read it once or twice. This also has the effect of debouncing a mechanical switch. You can extend this method to ensure the switch is active for a given time to filter out effects of vibration or a false press.
This is the advantage the doing debouncing in software gives you.

In general, you should filter any input from the outside world - transients are common place. One read of a GPIO is a snapshot of a few nanoseconds - a transient can easily 'photo-bomb' the value you read. This is also one reason why you should avoid using switches and external signals on external interrupts.

As for a suggestion of a schmitt trigger ic, something like a 74HC14 is fairly common.

Comment: Transients should not normally cause the state of the input to transition all the way from low to high or vice verse. I have seen it happen, but only when there was a long trace attached to an input with no external pullup or pulldown. Even then, adding a small capacitor (like 22pF) fixed the problem.

Comment: Depends on the transient and how you test for it. Ever done CE testing?

Comment: yes. During ESD testing sometimes an input can transition. But generally not if it has a strong pullup or strong pulldown, or if it has a capacitor. Usually it is something driven weakly that transitions. Or something with a long wire. I still think you have kind of overstated the case when you say "a transient can easily 'photo-bomb' the value you read." But I have no major quarrel with you. I largely agree with what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Any hardware solution to debouncing involves a certain time latency, what time T between button presses is considered to be a bounce, or a second press?

Once you have that time T, the simplest way to debounce is to poll the button once every T in software.

There are plenty of more complicated schemes you can find being pushed on the web, sampling more often and implementing up and down counters, but they don't really offer you much advantage over the simplest poll every T.

Comment: Actually polling every time T isn't a great idea, as this can lead to missing events entirely.  Typically what you want to do is detect the leading event *immediately* and then *ignore* any subsequent input for time T.  A variation is to detect closure, but wait to act until the button has been *released* for an entire time T.

Comment: If you poll every 10ms are you concerned about missing a sub 10ms pushbutton event? If it is sub 10ms, then it is unlikely it is a valid pushbutton press.

Comment: @Kartman if you poll every 10 ms, possibility of misreading the same event for multiple times is there. Imagining the switch is poor in debouncing and is triggering an interrupt in the code. If you increase the polling time, possibility of missing an event increases. Gotta find a trade off between two. But still this is a crude method.

Comment: @mituraj. If polling is crude, what would you suggest is a more suitable technique? Suggesting an interrupt would be worse - you want sub microsecond response for an input that is derived from slow human input? What about EMC effects?

Comment: This is not a place for me to answer. Chris has already mentioned in his comment more reliable method. You can research on that as it's popular in embedded coding to debounce using counters/shift registers.

Comment: @mituraj. I’m confused. The technique of sampling is based on DSP techniques and you’re saying its crude and unreliable? Have you read Ganssle’s work?

Comment: For buttons, polling every 10 or 50 ms works well in practice. Missing button presses that last less than 50ms is not a problem, as these are very fleeting button presses that were probably done by accident. Maye for a game controller it might be important to reduce latency. But for many normal buttons it is fine.